# Compare 2 CSV files in JMeter

Tags: java, csv, groovy, jmeter-5.0, filecompare

[Screen capture of Result tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LScu.png)

Code keeps running in infinite loop , wheather the data matches or not. 
 Also i want to ignore the first/header column when comparing. Can you
please help with this.
Thanks

I am using below code to compare 2 csv files.

Input Files:

*File1*

```
ColumnA
A
B
C
```

*File2*

```
ColumnA
A
B
D
```

Code

```
#import java.io.File;#
#import java.io.FileReader;#
#import java.io.LineNumberReader;#

String strfile1 = vars.get("thisScriptPath") + "file1.csv";
String strfile2 = vars.get("thisScriptPath") + "file2.csv";

def file1 = new File('/path/to/file1')
def file2 = new File('/path/to/file2')

def file1Lines = file1.readLines('UTF-8')
def file2Lines = file2.readLines('UTF-8')

if (file1Lines.size() != file2Lines.size()) {
    SampleResult.setSussessful(false)
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage('Files size is different, omitting line-by-line compare')
} else {
    def differences = new StringBuilder()

   file1Lines.eachWithIndex { String file1Line, int number ->
       String file2Line = file2Lines.get(number)
       if (!file1Line.equals(file2Line)) {
           differences.append('Difference # ').append(number).append('. Expected:        ').append(file1Line).append('. Actual: ' + file2Line)
           differences.append(System.getProperty('line.separator'))
       }
    }

    if (differences.toString().length() > 0) {
        SampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
        SampleResult.setResponseMessage(differences.toString())
    }
}
```

[REFER IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LScu.png)

Comment: To ignore the first line, just put an `if (number > 0)` right inside your `eachwithIndex` closure.  I don't immediately see anything else in your code that would cause it to run in an infinite loop.